# Are varieties normal if and only if they are analytically normal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Let $V$ be a normal variety, and $p \in V$ a point. It is a theorem of Zariski[1] that the completion $\hat{\mathcal O}_{V,p}$ is a normal ring.

Does the converse also hold? Does $\hat{\mathcal O}_{V,p}$ normal, imply that $\mathcal O_{V,p}$ is normal as well?

[1] Zariski, *Sur la normalité analytique des variétés normales*, 1950

Comment: See Stacks, Lemma 033G.

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks, that works! If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer. $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{V,p}$ is the completion of $\mathcal{O}_{V,p}$ (a Noetherian local ring) at its maximal ideal, and therefore is faithfully flat. By [Stacks, Lemma 033G](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/033G), if $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{V,p}$ is normal, then so is $\mathcal{O}_{V,p}$.